# Rounded prototype corners iOS9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9.2

How would I change my cells in the UITableViewCells to have rounded corners? Kind of like this:

[image: Rounded corners on cells]

I like the gaps that are present, so is there away to adjust that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ContentView of the UITableViewCell you can set, this lines the get the rounded corner.

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
self.clipsToBounds = true
self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

To give the gap, you need to set the default content view to Clear Color (to be transparent), and add a View inside the cell, with a smaller size then the cell.

It will look like this in the storyboard.
[image]